# change attr of text into "readonly false" inside of the javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have here a html code inside the javascript one and it will append that on my modal, my question is how can I set to `readonly=false` property in order textbox to be enabled. I'm trying jquery but it's not working. The group of textboxes must be enabled when calling the class.

```
<script>
  var html;
 for ( x=0 ; x < 5 ; x++)
  {
    html +=' <input type="text" class="changeintofalse" readonly/>';
  }

  $('#details_info').html(html);
  $('#itemsModal').modal('show');
</script>
```

Comment: Note that you have some syntax errors. The parentheses go around the variable declarations in the `for`: `for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {`. Also in your HTML string `>\';` needs to be `/>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I set to `readonly=false` property in order textbox to be enabled

There is no `readonly="false"` setting. If the `readonly` attribute exists on the element, with *any* value, then the field will be readonly.

If you want to make the element editable again you need to *remove* that attribute. Using jQuery the best practice would be to use `prop()`:

```
$('#foo').prop('readonly', false);
```

However using `removeAttr()` will work too:

```
$('#foo').removeAttr('readonly');
```

Comment: i already tried, but i think jquery is not working, when my html code is inside of javascript. but thanks for the help.

Comment: For this to work you need to either place the HTML you generated in to a jQuery object, or append it to the DOM first and then perform this action. Either way, it works.

Comment: No problem, glad to help